# What's the difference between thread_posixs and thread_win32 in gcc port of Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, gcc4.7

I wanted to download the latest available version of `gcc 4.7.2` compiler for Windows. When I got to this [page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds/files/host-windows/releases/4.7.2/32-bit/) where I was supposed to see a download link, I confronted with two categories:

1. threads-posix
2. threads-win32

What's the difference between these two? Are they thread implementations only? I mean are they only different in how they are implemented and thus the ending result (classes, how to use them, etc) remains the same? Or do they impose a specific coding style?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

So, the link you provided leads to builds of the standalone gcc 4.7.2 for windows, a.k.a mingw64. In order to build this compiler, a set of scripts are used, which help define the options of compilations. The scripts are simply called MinGW-builds, and can be found in different places:

- [google code](https://code.google.com/p/mingw-builds)
- [github fork](https://github.com/niXman/mingw-builds)

The scripts have an option which specify which thread model is to be used for the std::threads part of the C++11 standard (this is allowed for MinGW thanks to an [experimental patch](http://tehsausage.com/mingw-std-thread-gcc-4-7) applied on that version of GCC). 
In one case, the win32 thread API is used, and in the other case it's the posix API which is used.

*Note that Windows doesn't support all the POSIX API out of the box, so some external emulation library needs to be used (winpthreads).*

The GCC source configure script has an option to specify that API (--enable-threads=), and that's what is used in the build scripts.

In short, for this version of mingw, the threads-posix release will use the posix API and **allow the use of std::thread**, and the threads-win32 will use the win32 API, and **disable the std::thread part of the standard**.

Comment: For completeness (because it only works for 5.3.0 and up), https://github.com/meganz/mingw-std-threads makes it possible to use std::thread with the win32 threading model.