# Thread class library based on C++11

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, mingw

C++11 introduced [`<thread>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread) in its standard draft. But [MingGW-4.7](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html) doesn't support it.

Is there any attempt to implement threads based on [`std::thread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) which covers the lack of MingGW-4.7 ?

I want use it in my project and after upgrading the compiler, I'll just replace it with standard C++11 thread library by minor changes.

Comment: What platform are you using? GCC 4.7 does support `std::thread`.

Comment: @juanchopanza: MinGW on Windows

Comment: @AndyProwl: No Boost in my special case.

Comment: @MM. I think you need ported pthread libraries to use `<thread>` in MinGW-4.7.

Comment: [The builds here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds/) support threads.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13212342/whats-the-difference-between-thread-posixs-and-thread-win32-in-gcc-port-of-windo

Comment: Why no boost? I suspect you can extract the thread module.

Comment: @AlexChamberlain: You mean it's possible to separate thread module? If it's possible and Boost's thread is based on std::thread. I'll use it.

Comment: @MM.: The other way round I would say: Boost.Thread inspired std::thread. So you have quite a good chance that replacing `boost::` with `std::` will be everything you'll have to do after

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `std::thread` with MinGW, user [rubenvb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/256138/rubenvb) keeps MinGW64 builds that have `std::thread` in [Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Personal%20Builds/rubenvb/gcc-4.8-experimental-stdthread/)

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [MinGW-builds](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds/files/host-windows/releases/). Choose compilers marked as 'posix-thread', they are implements C++11 multi-threading support with pthread library.