# Mingw + clang vs Boost under Windows: different kind of errors

Tags: c++, windows, boost, mingw, llvm-clang

I have prepared a llvm-clang compiler targeting 32bit Windows. I used 3.7.1 and applied [this patch](http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/cfe-commits/Week-of-Mon-20150803/135129.html). I get to something that *almost* works, apart that I have errors with boost.

If I compile my project (that normally works with mingw-gcc) using my usual boost 1.53 headers I have troubles including [boost/interprocess](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/interprocess.html) components

```
In file included from [...]/Boost/include-WINDOWS/boost-1_53\boost/interprocess/sync/interprocess_semaphore.hpp:24:
In file included from [...]/Boost/include-WINDOWS/boost-1_53\boost/interprocess/exceptions.hpp:20:
In file included from [...]/Boost/include-WINDOWS/boost-1_53\boost/interprocess/errors.hpp:37:
[...]/Boost/include-WINDOWS/boost-1_53\boost/interprocess/detail/win32_api.hpp:878:48: error: conflicting types for 'VirtualProtect'
```

If I then try to [recompile boost](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13257930/2436175) with:

```
bootstrap.bat mingw
b2 toolset=clang --with-thread --with-filesystem --with-signals --with-test --with-system --with-regex --with-program_options --with-serialization variant=release link=shared threading=multi
```

Depending on the various version of boost I get a lot of warnings that I could try to ignore, but also some errors:

For 1.56 and 1.57 just these: (is not much, but I don't know how to get rid of it)

```
In file included from libs\serialization\src\xml_wiarchive.cpp:35:
.\boost/archive/impl/archive_serializer_map.ipp:41:34: error: redeclaration of 'boost::archive::detail::archive_serializer_map::insert' cannot add 'dllexport' attribute
archive_serializer_map<Archive>::insert(const basic_serializer * bs){
                                 ^
.\boost/archive/detail/archive_serializer_map.hpp:42:17: note: previous declaration is here
    static bool insert(const basic_serializer * bs);
                ^
In file included from libs\serialization\src\xml_wiarchive.cpp:35:
.\boost/archive/impl/archive_serializer_map.ipp:49:34: error: redeclaration of 'boost::archive::detail::archive_serializer_map::erase' cannot add 'dllexport' attribute
archive_serializer_map<Archive>::erase(const basic_serializer * bs){
                                 ^
.\boost/archive/detail/archive_serializer_map.hpp:43:17: note: previous declaration is here
    static void erase(const basic_serializer * bs);
                ^
In file included from libs\serialization\src\xml_wiarchive.cpp:35:
.\boost/archive/impl/archive_serializer_map.ipp:61:34: error: redeclaration of 'boost::archive::detail::archive_serializer_map::find' cannot add 'dllexport' attribute
archive_serializer_map<Archive>::find(
                                 ^
.\boost/archive/detail/archive_serializer_map.hpp:44:37: note: previous declaration is here
    static const basic_serializer * find(
                                    ^
```

For 1.59 and 1.60 a bunch of MMX related error, which is, as far as I can see, not a feature that I can control when preparing my llvm-clang:

```
clang-linux.compile.c++.without-pth bin.v2\libs\thread\build\clang-linux-3.7.1\debug\threading-multi\win32\thread.obj
In file included from libs\thread\src\win32\thread.cpp:17:
In file included from .\boost/thread/thread_only.hpp:15:
In file included from .\boost/thread/win32/thread_data.hpp:11:
In file included from .\boost/thread/win32/thread_primitives.hpp:18:
In file included from .\boost/detail/interlocked.hpp:154:
In file included from C:\Programs\LLVM\bin\..\lib\clang\3.7.1\include\intrin.h:26:
In file included from C:\Programs\MinGW\i686-w64-mingw32\include\Intrin.h:154:
In file included from C:\Programs\LLVM\bin\..\lib\clang\3.7.1\include\mm3dnow.h:27:
C:\Programs\LLVM\bin\..\lib\clang\3.7.1\include\mmintrin.h:28:2: error: "MMX instruction set not enabled"
#error "MMX instruction set not enabled"
 ^
In file included from libs\thread\src\win32\thread.cpp:17:
In file included from .\boost/thread/thread_only.hpp:15:
In file included from .\boost/thread/win32/thread_data.hpp:11:
In file included from .\boost/thread/win32/thread_primitives.hpp:18:
In file included from .\boost/detail/interlocked.hpp:154:
In file included from C:\Programs\LLVM\bin\..\lib\clang\3.7.1\include\intrin.h:26:
In file included from C:\Programs\MinGW\i686-w64-mingw32\include\Intrin.h:154:
C:\Programs\LLVM\bin\..\lib\clang\3.7.1\include\mm3dnow.h:42:41: error: use of undeclared identifier '__v8qi'
  return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_pavgusb((__v8qi)__m1, (__v8qi)__m2);
                                        ^
C:\Programs\LLVM\bin\..\lib\clang\3.7.1\include\mm3dnow.h:42:55: error: use of undeclared identifier '__v8qi'
  return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_pavgusb((__v8qi)__m1, (__v8qi)__m2);
                                                      ^
C:\Programs\LLVM\bin\..\lib\clang\3.7.1\include\mm3dnow.h:47:38: error: cannot convert '__m64' to '__v2sf' (vector of 2 'float' values) without a conversion operator
  return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_pf2id((__v2sf)__m);
                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Programs\LLVM\bin\..\lib\clang\3.7.1\include\mm3dnow.h:52:38: error: cannot convert '__m64' to '__v2sf' (vector of 2 'float' values) without a conversion operator
  return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_pfacc((__v2sf)__m1, (__v2sf)__m2);
                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Programs\LLVM\bin\..\lib\clang\3.7.1\include\mm3dnow.h:52:52: error: cannot convert '__m64' to '__v2sf' (vector of 2 'float' values) without a conversion operator
  return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_pfacc((__v2sf)__m1, (__v2sf)__m2);
                                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Is there a way to get any version of boost to work with clang 32bit under Windows in a MinGW set up?

I have also tried llvm 3.8.0, but I cannot prepare it because my MinGW toolchain doesn't support some part of C++11 (and so other versions that I have tried, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17551722/2436175)).

Comment: For the second problem, it could be related to [this patch](http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvm-commits/Week-of-Mon-20151109/312887.html)

Answer (score 0):

As to boost.thread:
After adding -msse (or whatever) (that resolves MMX instruction set not enabled error) just add -DBOOST_USE_WINDOWS_H to cxxflags to resolve different declarations of many system functions at Windows headers and at boost.date_time.

Eg:
cxxflags="-msse -DBOOST_USE_WINDOWS_H"