# Cannot find #include <mutex> when trying to use std::mutex

Tags: c++, cmake

When I am trying to compile or include the relevant header file for std::mutex, it cannot be found. I suspect the issue is related to my CMake but as I am new to it, I am not sure what is missing.

This is my CMake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(display)
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++")
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp Display.cpp Display.h Utilities.cpp Utilities.h)
add_executable(display ${SOURCE_FILES})

set(MY_TEST_SOURCES Display_test.cpp Utilities.cpp Display.cpp)
add_executable(display_test ${MY_TEST_SOURCES})
```

[image]

Comment: Not so long ago, the standard MinGW did not support thread or mutexes.

Comment: Is this it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17551722/getting-stdthread-mutex-to-work-under-win7-with-mingw-and-g-4-7-2

Comment: @KABoissonneault, I will give it a try and let you know in a moment. Thank you.

Comment: This is what I am using: http://mingw-w64.yaxm.org/doku.php According to their documentation, it should support that.

Comment: Search your hard drive.  Is there a copy of a file called `mutex` on it?  Examine your include paths.  Is that header file in your include path?  (Note: I'm not saying "blindly add such a header file to your include path", as it might be from a different compiler and horribly break your install if you try it, I'm just asking questions)

Comment: Probably unrelated, but you haven't defined your CMake project to be C++.

Comment: @usr1234567, I thought "set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)" does that? Can you please point what is missing?

Comment: @user3270371 "By default C and CXX are enabled if no language options are given."