# MinGW error: ‘thread’ is not a member of ‘std’

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, mingw

I'm trying to cross-compile for Windows a simple application:

```
#include <thread>

void Func(){
  return;
}

int main(){
  std::thread thr1(Func);
  thr1.detach();
  return 0;
}
```

And that's what I get:

```
$ i686-w64-mingw32-g++ -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc -pipe -g -std=c++0x ./threadstutor.cpp 
./threadstutor.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
./threadstutor.cpp:8:3: error: ‘thread’ is not a member of ‘std’
./threadstutor.cpp:8:15: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘thr1’
./threadstutor.cpp:9:3: error: ‘thr1’ was not declared in this scope
```

Actually, this code have no such problem if compile with g++ for Ubuntu; but I need to cross-compile for Windows, and here I'm stuck.

Comment: If you are compiling this on windows, you will need Mingw-Builds v4.8.1 with posix-threads: http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds/files/host-windows/releases/4.8.1/64-bit/threads-posix/sjlj/  You can choose between sjlj and seh. Seh is only x64 and sjlj is both x32 and x64.

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames i'm compiling it on Ubuntu. I have latest mingw from repository; _"i686-w64-mingw32-g++ --version"_ says _"i686-w64-mingw32-g++ (GCC) 4.6.3"_

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames though if I didn't find the solution, I could use it as some kind of workaround: run MinGW through wine to compile the source. Although it's weird :D
By the way, is my version of compiler doesn't support _std::thread_'s?

Comment: I don't think 4.6.3 every support threads for Windows executables.. I think `std::thread` came in at 4.7+. Maybe an update might fix it. Always worth a shot.

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames alas, there is still no success. I found on a site of MinGW link to latest build, then tried to compile with it. But the error rest the same. Version of this g++ is _4.9.0 20131227_ Seems, it's time to give up with STL, and use multi-threading support of MFC :(

Comment: try printing `g++ --version` and make sure it is actually using the right one. Other than that, I'm not sure why you can't use `std::thread`. Weird.

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames Yes, i'm sure. 
`$ ./i686-w64-mingw32-g++ --version` says 
`i686-w64-mingw32-g++ (GCC) 4.9.0 20131227 (experimental).....`, and 
`$ ./i686-w64-mingw32-g++ ~/Projects/WinCrossCmplng/StilsoftTest/threadstutor.cpp -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc -pipe -g -std=c++11` still talking the same error
`...error: ‘thread’ is not a member of ‘std’...` Sorry for awful formatting.

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames I found a strange thing! I just tried to download Windows version of MinGW and run it with wine. And... it works! The version number _4.8.1_, it's surely lower than previous build which I tried. Anyway, it's works!

Comment: @Brandon I am very thankful to you. Right now I couldn't find a MinGW link to download at all! The site gave me either linux version of MinGW(I am for some reason need a GNU/linux one), either installer which doesn't work because I am behind a proxy. Then I am recalled you old comment. Thank you very much!

Comment: There is no linux version of MinGW. The W means Windows

Comment: @M.M [There is](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=mingw&searchon=names&suite=xenial&section=all). How else am I supposed to compile Windows app from GNU/Linux? ☺

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mingw-w64 threads: posix vs win32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17242516/mingw-w64-threads-posix-vs-win32)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This error means that the STL you are using does not contain all the features of C++11.

To access C++11 threads in Windows, you will need a build of Mingw with posix-threads. Here you can find Mingw-Builds v4.8.1: http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds/files/host-windows/releases/4.8.1/64-bit/threads-posix/sjlj/

Comment: Couldn't install. It is showing "can not download repository.txt [0]"

Comment: How about mingw installed on Linux via `sudo apt-get install mingw-w64`?

Comment: @NaveenKumar see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51747358/mingw-w64-cannot-download-repository-txt-error - I solved the issue with chocolatey package manager.

Answer (score 18):

There is already a better option:
https://github.com/meganz/mingw-std-threads
This is a lightweight win32 native implementation of the most used threading and synchronization C++11 classes for MinGW. These are implemented in a header-only library that can co-exist with the system libs. It supports Windows XP as well, which does not have a direct analog of conditional variables.

Answer (score 0):

On Window, you can choice to use POSIX thread lib to construct your app.
You can find it via https://sourceforge.net/projects/pthreads4w/files/

Comment: There are easier solutions than manually setting up this library. You can just install MinGW-w64 (one of its numerous distributions), which should have multithreading library features by default.

Comment: This suggestion seems to have already been mentioned [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21879380/2388257) here.

Answer (score 0):

`std::thread` was introduced in C++11, but you are not compiling for C++11 (or later).  Look at the command you showed:

> $ i686-w64-mingw32-g++ -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc -pipe -g **-std=c++0x** ./threadstutor.cpp

`-std=c++0x` predates the official release of C++11.  Use `-std=c++11` instead.

See [What is the difference between -std=c++0x and -std=c++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24589105/)

Comment: The question you refer to has accepted answer that claims for `c++0x` and `c++11` to be the same thing for compilers from times before C++11 got stable. Also note the last sentence `When the compiler supports both, they should be identical`. One could speculate that this API being "unstable" meant lack of `std∷threads` in the context of the question here. However, from what I recall and judging by the accepted answer here, the problem was simply the odd decision of MinGW maintainers to release two versions: with and without threads support.