# g++ error: ‘to_string’ was not declared in this scope. Tried adding -std=c++0x

Tags: c++, g++, cygwin

Been having the problem for a while. Searched thoroughly on stackoverflow and other sites to figure out the problem.

I have c++2011, using the latest version of cygwin for terminal, and GCC 4.8.3. I tried adding -std=c++0x and -std=gnu++0x to the command line, but neither of them fixed the problem. Here's the code I've been using the test if it will work.  to anyone who can help!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int a = 1;
    string b = to_string(a);
    cout<< b;
    return 0; 
}
```

Here's what I used to compile as well as the error:

> $ g++ -std=gnu++0x stringTest.cpp -o stringTest 
>   stringTest.cpp: In function ‘int main()’: stringTest.cpp:8:24: error: ‘to_string’ was not
>   declared in this scope   string b = to_string(a);
>
> ```
>                     ^
> ```

Anyone have any idea what's going on? I have an assignment due soon that I have to use this for and really need to get it working. Thanks in advance

Comment: Try with the `-std=c++11` option

Comment: @Cyber `-std=c++0x` and `-std=c++11` are supposed to have exactly the same effect. Do you have a concrete reason to think it might make a difference?

Comment: See [`std::to_string()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string)

Comment: @DieterLücking `using namespace std;` *should* cover that, should it not?

Comment: @hvd No not concrete, more like a suspicion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24589105/what-is-the-difference-between-std-c0x-and-std-c11

Comment: Works fine - linux g++ 4.8.2

Comment: For MinGW, [there is a comment in the GCC bugzilla that this cannot be implemented for 32-bit compilations due to limitations of the libraries used by GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52015#c15). I'm not sure, but this might affect Cygwin as well.

Comment: Tried using -std=c++11 and that didn't work either. I've tried this on two separate computers as well. Bother running latest cygwin, and GCC 4.8.3.

Comment: @hvd, running x64 version of cygwin. How would I check to see if GCC is x86 or x64?

Comment: @AubreySapp In that case, if you installed GCC through Cygwin's setup, you should have an x64 version. To double-check, you could run `gcc -v` and see what it says for "Target". Unfortunately, if you've got an x64 version and it doesn't work, that means it's just not implemented for Cygwin. However, since you have an x64 OS, you could install the MinGW version of GCC and use that instead.

Comment: @hvd Target says "x86_64-pc-cygwin"

Comment: The "duplicate" talks about g++/MinGW, but this question is about g++/Cygwin (those are different products).  g++/Cygwin does have the same bug though.

Comment: the gcc discussion thread is a pretty lame copout, it would be possible to implement this function without relying on other libraries. Perhaps better to say "nobody has the time/inclination to fix it" than "impossible".