# GCC 4.9.2 on ARMHF missing std::mutex

Tags: c++11, arm, g++, debian, libstdc++

I'm working on an embedded project which will be using an arm7-a (armhf) system on a chip running Debian Jessie.

This system includes GCC/G++ 4.9.2, which *should* be fully C++11 compatible.

However, I'm seeing issues like, `std::mutex` and `std::condition_variable` not being present in the `std` namespace. I believe this is because the `_GLIBCXX_HAS_GTHREADS` macro isn't defined. I've found this to be the case whether I pass `-std=gnu++0x` or `-std=c++11`.

Does anybody know if this is expected behaviour on this platform?

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21211980/mingw-error-thread-is-not-a-member-of-std Can you confirm with `gcc -v` that threading is enabled in your gcc configuration?

Comment: The output of `gcc -v` contains `--enable-threads=posix`