# Mingw-w64 "Cannot download repository.txt" Error

Tags: matlab, windows-7, mingw-w64

I am trying to install MinGW-w64 in Windows 7.

[image: Running .exe file].

but I keep getting the error:

> "Cannot download repository.txt".

[image: Error]

I have read multiple threads about this and downloaded multiple .exe files but none of them work for me. I have MATLAB R2016a with the bug to use the Add-ons window. I tried to install MinGW-w64 directly with some work-arounds but nothing worked. So I am trying to install MinGW-w64 directly into Windows 7 and then assign it to MATLAB as the Compiler to enable me to build s-functions in Simulink.

How to fix this problem?

Comment: Do you have internet? can you run that .exe in admin mode?

Comment: Yes, i have good internet. Just try running it as Admin and have the same issue. This is a business computer, maybe our IT team is blocking me some how.

Comment: I am having the same problem. Were you able to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I have the same error message:

> Cannot download `repository.txt`

and I have 2 alternative solutions to install MinGW-w64 in windows :

**SOLUTION 1**:
Install [chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/). Then type the following command line:

```
c:> choco install mingw
```

**SOLUTION 2:**
Download [MinGW](https://osdn.net/projects/mingw/releases/) build ("native Windows" build). Then I was able to make GFortran work on JetBrain CLion.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, could you describe a bit more in details the second solution?