# VSCode: 'thread' is not a member of 'std'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, mingw

I copy this code and compile it but I got some error

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

struct F
{
  void operator() () const
  {
    std::cout<<"Printing from another thread"<<std::endl;
  }
};

int main()
{
  F f;
  std::thread t(f);
  t.join();

  return 0;
}
```

Error:
`'thread' is not a member of 'std'`

But I have added "includePath" well and "defines" in "c_cpp_properties.json" so I don't know why the errors exists.

The "c_cpp_properties.json" is like this:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceRoot}",
                "C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/include/c++",
                "C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/include/c++/mingw32",
                "C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/include/c++/backward",
                "C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/include",
                "C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../include",
                "C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/include-fixed",
                "C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/include"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "__cdecl=__attribute__((__cdecl__))"
            ],
            "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64",
            "browse": {
                "path": [
                    "${workspaceRoot}",
                    "C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/include/",
                    "C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../include",
                    "C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/include-fixed"
                ],
                "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
                "databaseFilename": ""
            },
            "compilerPath": "C:/mingw64/bin/g++.exe",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++11"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

And "settings.json" is like this (code-runner)

```
{
    "git.autofetch": true,
    "editor.wordWrap": "on",
    "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
    "java.home": "C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_201/",
    "workbench.settings.editor": "ui",
    "code-runner.executorMap": {
        "javascript": "node",
        "java": "cd $dir && javac $fileName && java $fileNameWithoutExt",
        "c": "cd $dirWithoutTrailingSlash && gcc $fileName -g -o $fileNameWithoutExt && ./$fileNameWithoutExt.exe",

        // 
        //"cpp": "cd $dirWithoutTrailingSlash && g++ $fileName -g -o $fileNameWithoutExt && ./$fileNameWithoutExt.exe < d.dat",

        "cpp": "cd $dirWithoutTrailingSlash && g++ $fileName -g -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $fileNameWithoutExt.exe",
        "objective-c": "cd $dir && gcc -framework Cocoa $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
        "php": "php",
        "python": "python",
        "perl": "perl",
        "perl6": "perl6",
        "ruby": "ruby",
        "go": "go run",
        "lua": "lua",
        "groovy": "groovy",
        "powershell": "powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File",
        "bat": "cmd /c",
        "shellscript": "bash",
        "fsharp": "fsi",
        "csharp": "scriptcs",
        "vbscript": "cscript //Nologo",
        "typescript": "ts-node",
        "coffeescript": "coffee",
        "scala": "scala",
        "swift": "swift",
        "julia": "julia",
        "crystal": "crystal",
        "ocaml": "ocaml",
        "r": "Rscript",
        "applescript": "osascript",
        "clojure": "lein exec",
        "haxe": "haxe --cwd $dirWithoutTrailingSlash --run $fileNameWithoutExt",
        "rust": "cd $dir && rustc $fileName && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
        "racket": "racket",
        "ahk": "autohotkey",
        "autoit": "autoit3",
        "dart": "dart",
        "pascal": "cd $dir && fpc $fileName && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
        "d": "cd $dir && dmd $fileName && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
        "haskell": "runhaskell",
        "nim": "nim compile --verbosity:0 --hints:off --run"
    },
    "code-runner.runInTerminal": true,
    "files.exclude": {
        "**/.classpath": true,
        "**/.project": true,
        "**/.settings": true,
        "**/.factorypath": true
    },
    "java.errors.incompleteClasspath.severity": "ignore",
}
```

Is the cpp compile way set in settings.json wrong? 
If I change cpp compile method in json file to comment, when I press ctrl+alt+n, it is going the way it was setup.

Or is it better to install pthread?

Comment: Is this c++? Please add the tag.

Comment: I think the editor tag (`visual-studio-code`) should be replaced with `mingw`.

Comment: pthread? If you can use `std::thread` and it does what you need, use that.

Comment: but std::thread can not work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MinGW error: ‘thread’ is not a member of ‘std’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21211980/mingw-error-thread-is-not-a-member-of-std)