# gcc giving error when initiating thread class

Tags: c++, multithreading, class, object

I've been having an error declaring a thread class object. I tried this code and it gave me the error "'thread' was not declared in this scope". If it helps, I'm compiling to Windows using MinGW GCC.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
using namespace std;

void func(){
    cout << "Hello from thread 2\n";
}
int main(){
    cout << "Hello from thread 1\n";
    thread t2(func);
    t2.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling gives me "`error: 'thread' was not declared in this scope`"

Comment: ***I'm compiling to Windows using MinGW GCC*** Too old a version? The current MinGW has gcc-11.2

Comment: @drescherjm, I just got my MinGW from SourceForge. maybe there is a better place to get it? My MinGW installer only shows an option for gcc-6.3.0-1. Is mingw-w64.org legit?

Comment: Did you turn on C++11 or higher?

Comment: I assumed it would automatically compile c++11. The thread file does exist and defines the thread class..

Comment: possible dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21211980/mingw-error-thread-is-not-a-member-of-std

Comment: The compiler defaults to the stone age, enabling c++11 just gets you to the bronze age. Join the modern age, use -std=c++20 and enjoy having `std::jthread`.

Comment: thread class seems to be in the std namespace, according to the thread file I have. The MinGW-builds-install.exe file referenced by @NathanOliver gives errors...

Comment: *"I assumed [...]"* -- first or second rule of debugging: question all assumptions!

Comment: *"My MinGW installer only shows an option for gcc-6.3.0-1"* -- is that what you actually have installed? The default for gcc 6.1 through 10 is C++14. You might want to check what you are actually using to compile. Look at the command used to compile for any "-std" options and also run `gcc --version` to verify what version you are actually running.

Comment: gcc --version return gcc-6.3.0-1. I just tried Cygwin gcc (version 11 point something) and it gave some big long error

Comment: 11. anything shouldn't have a problem, and cygwin is a POSIX compatibility layer, so if it doesn't have threading over Pthreads, I'll be a monkey's uncle. Mind you, I just might be. My nephew needs to be seen to be believed. Give us real code and the error messages and someone here can help you out.

Comment: Ditch your MinGW version and download [MSYS2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30069830/2752075). They usually have a more up-to-date version than mingw-w64.org, and the package manager with prebuilt libraries is good.

Comment: I am using msys2 to install mingw and the builtin package management to install many open source libraries.

Answer (score -2):

Threads are missing in mingw, but you can use some library like this one [mingw-std-threads](https://github.com/meganz/mingw-std-threads).

Comment: Threads are missing in some Stone Age distributions of MinGW. I haven't had a problem in the last six or seven years, but some of those hoary old beasts just won't die. Shouldn't be a surprise seeing as we still get Turbo C++ questions.