# MinGW 4.8.1 C++11 thread support

Tags: gcc, c++11, g++, mingw

I downloaded the version of MinGW from the official website: http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/ and installed it on my Windows 7 machine.

Running `g++ --version` gives me `g++.exe (GCC) 4.8.1` and I believe GCC 4.8.1 has support for C++11 features, including threads.

Running `g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp` successfully compiles the following program.

```
//main.cpp
#include <memory>

int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<int> a(new int);
    return 0;
}
```

But running `g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp` on the following program:

```
//main.cpp
#include <mutex>

int main() {
    std::mutex myMutex;
    return 0;
}
```

gives errors:

```
main.cpp: In function `int main()`:
main.cpp:5:5: error: 'mutex' is not a member of 'std'
    std::mutex myMutex;
    ^
main.cpp:5:16: error: expected ';' before 'myMutex'
    std::mutex myMutex;
                ^
```

as if `<mutex>` is not supported. The compiler does not complain about `#include <mutex>` so I have no idea why I'm getting this error.

Comment: I see I don't have this problem on cygwin gcc 4.8.3. Perhaps you could take a look into your mutex header - maybe you can spot something weird in there. Unless installed somewhere else it's location should be something like this /lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.8.1/include/c++/mutex.

Comment: I'm using MinGW not cygwin

Comment: Ok. My bad ... However taking a look into that header may be useful. After all the compiler seems not to find mutex inside the std namespace.

Comment: Which MinGW version do you exactly use? In particular, which thread model does your version support: win32 or posix?

Comment: My MinGW has a .dll package called "mingw32-libpthreadgc" or "POSIX threading library for Win32". But this is just the runtime library, so I just installed a package called mingw32-pthreads-w32, a "POSIX threading library for Win32", which contains the headers and development files. I thought that would fix it, but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: You can try the following build [mingw-build](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/latest/download?source=files). Choose the posix threading model.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17242516/mingw-w64-threads-posix-vs-win32 which is the state of the art for mingw-w64, no idea on mingw main...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I understand well, std threading is still not supported on mingw, but some mingw-w64 builds support it. Fortunately, you can still build 32-bit apps using this version of mingw.

Here is the [link for the builds](http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/download.php#mingw-builds).

Comment: To clarify: using a pthread build (either pre-compiled, or if you select pthread from the mingw-w64 installer) works out-of-the box; using a win32-thread build you need to use the meganz addon as described in Alexander Vassilev's answer.

Answer (score 9):

There is already a native win32 implementation of std::thread and sync primitives:
https://github.com/meganz/mingw-std-threads
It is a header-only library and should work with any C++11 compliant version of MinGW.