# Codeblocks C++ threading error

Tags: c++, multithreading, codeblocks

I have a problem including the thread library. The following code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

//The function we want to make the thread run.
void task1(string msg)
{
    cout << "task1 says: " << msg;
}

int main()
{
    // Constructs the new thread and runs it. Does not block execution.
    thread t1(task1, "Hello");

    //Makes the main thread wait for the new thread to finish execution, therefore blocks its own execution.
    t1.join();
}
```

Produces these errors:

[image]

The code is taken from the answer to another stackoverflow question. I am fairly new to codeblocks and C++ so please explain to me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Okay, it is indeed weird. What I'd probably wanted to know: can you find the header `thread` itself, and look at there? It would be in path `/usr/include/c++/SomeVersion/thread` in GNU/Linux, and, I guess, somewhere in `…/include/c++/SomeVersion/thread` in Windows® *(in the latter case you need to search a little)*. You have to find whether somewhere in that file a words `class thread`. From your problem I am guessing that the header somehow screwed.

Comment: @Hi-Angel: It appears the out of the box TDM compiler with Code::Blocks is compiled without thread support. You have to download a different compiler and use that with Code::Blocks instead to get thread support.

Comment: If you are using mingw-w64 with win32 threads then you need to use the [meganz threading addon](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27421968/1505939)

Answer (score 0):

You probably have not set proper flags for compiler (so that it uses c++11). [Way of doing it in codeblocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18174988/how-can-i-add-c11-support-to-codeblocks-compiler)

Comment: In this case the compiler would complain about a support for C++11 not being enabled. I just even tested to be sure — compiled their example with `-std=c++03` flag.

Comment: No, that is everything that is being said when i run the code... Why wouldn't I post it all? It doesn't say anything about C++11 not being enabled. I enabled it the way Piotr said even before I posted this thread. The library is recognized when I type #include <thread> but whenever I try to use the thread function it doesn't show up

Comment: http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?topic=17841.0

Comment: @SkrewCodeBlocks: Your original question did not show everything. I updated your question with the complete output. In the forums discussion link in my previous comment, there is a link to a MinGW build that has the std::thread support built-in.

Comment: @jxh by the way, I just found an interesting thing: in the forum referenced by link folks mentioned that the issue with missing `thread` class is tied to license issues. So, I just out of curiosity tried to compile the example with MinGW being installed from Ubuntu repository, and… it works! :/ So strange.

Comment: @Hi-Angel: It's a windows thing.