# Specify thread model on ubuntu mingw (if possible)

Tags: c++, linux, g++, mingw-w64

Im running a program on linux with `g++` and everything works fine. If i compile using `x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++` it crashes with `error: ‘std::thread’ has not been declared`.

The part where my code crashed is fairly simple:

```
#include <thread>

int main()
{
    int cores = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
}
```

I figured out that mingw uses win32 threads, i want it to use posix threads. Version is:

```
:~$ x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3-win32/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32
Configured with: ../../src/configure --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr --includedir='/usr/include' --mandir='/usr/share/man' --infodir='/usr/share/info' --sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var --disable-silent-rules --libdir='/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' --libexecdir='/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' --disable-maintainer-mode --disable-dependency-tracking --prefix=/usr --enable-shared --enable-static --disable-multilib --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-tune=generic --with-headers=/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --enable-fully-dynamic-string --enable-libgomp --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++,ada --enable-lto --enable-threads=win32 --program-suffix=-win32 --program-prefix=x86_64-w64-mingw32- --target=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --with-as=/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-as --with-ld=/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld --enable-libatomic --enable-libstdcxx-filesystem-ts=yes --enable-dependency-tracking
Thread model: win32
gcc version 9.3-win32 20200320 (GCC)
```

As you can see thread model is win32, (how) can i change it? In the mingw include paths there is a 9.3-posix folder, but it seems it isnt used so far.

As you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17242516/mingw-w64-threads-posix-vs-win32) you can:

> I'm installing mingw-w64 on Windows and there are two options: win32 threads and posix threads.

Is that possible on linux aswell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the package `g++-mingw-w64-x86-64` provides two executables:

- `x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++-posix`: which uses posix
- `x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++-win32`: which uses win32

Using the first executable should solve your issue.

Comment: I love you, it works perfectly.
Out of curiousity, how did you find this? I did research for 2 days straigt.

Comment: @Zacki Thanks, I understand, I've been there before! I had to look around and found this out on this page I think https://packages.debian.org/sid/devel/g++-mingw-w64-x86-64. I'm glad that my previous efforts weren't in vain!